# SQL query to execute insert statement from the result of another sql query

Tags: sql

Guys i have to do a insert in to a table when there is no record found. is it possible to do it with only sql query. i tried with case and if .

Comment: Yup, I can confirm, it is possible and easy. Show us the source of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the condition of your 'IF' to the WHERE of the INSERT for example

```
INSERT INTO People
(FirstName,LastName,Email)
SELECT @FirstName,@LastName,@Email WHERE @Email NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM People)
```

If the email address already exists in the table then the SELECT will return no rows and hence no insert will take place

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
insert into table1 
   (select * from table2 where id not in
      (select id from table1))
```